# SQL how create a database user on windows？

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I create a user, it messages "error15063"

Comment: How you are creating the user ? Post the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

login already has an account under a different user name. (Error: 15063)

The login was mapped to the database as the dbo, which is wrong. It happened because this account actually created a database during the installation.

The login already has an account under a different user name. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15063)

To resolve this
Please run the script against your database: